# GWT DialogBox - setGlassEnabled(true) does not cover the whole window

Tags: gwt

I set glass enabled to true of a GWT dialog box. However, when the user has scrolled down in the window, then the "glass effect" does not cover the whole window anymore.

Does anyone know how to fix that? Many thanks for any advices![image]

Comment: You should set your popup to be modal, by calling `setModal(true)`.

Comment: I already do DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox(); dialogBox.setModal(true); dialogBox.setGlassEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1):

You need a css property such as

```
moveToPopUp.setGlassStyleName("myApp-PopupPanel-GlassStyle");
```

where

```
.myApp-PopupPanel-GlassStyle{
background-color            :   #333;
opacity                     :   0.4;
clip                        :   rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight fix available, but you can:
1. Remove scroll when showing popup with addStyleName, removeStyleName
2. There is also other solution, but you have to change layout of your style and will limit your functionality so I do not recommend this. But if you are interested I can describe this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
glassPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");
```

where `glassPanel` is the name of your panel,
be sure to include the import statement.

Comment: a css option would be better imo